# Go + MariaDB

Tags: golang, mariadb

Есть ли драйвер MariaDB для Go?

[Здесь](https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/SQLDrivers) не нашёл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ловите https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql